# ActiveAdmin limit records on Index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have some 10,000+ records in my model. In active_admin index page for that model I have set `config.paginate = false`. So all the 10,000+ records are shown by default.

How can I limit the number to say last 500 records. I have tried using the below method described [here](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#customizing_resource_retrieval), but its not doing anything to the index page.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      Post.all.limit(500)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

set custom # of rows on page with controller `before_filter`

```
controller do

   before_filter :set_per_page_var, :only => [:index]

   def set_per_page_var
     session[:per_page]=params[:per_page]||30
     @per_page = session[:per_page]
   end
end
```

and render sidebar with corresponding text input (you can render it as a drop-list)

```
#...

sidebar('Rows on page', :only => :index) do
  form do |f|
    f.text_field nil, 'per_page', :value => session[:per_page]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is [this code](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/99da460c38804de18fbb96fd07a0a62f05fca55f/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb#L263-L276) in Active Admin:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController < BaseController
    module DataAccess

      def per_page
        return max_csv_records if request.format == 'text/csv'
        return max_per_page if active_admin_config.paginate == false

        @per_page || active_admin_config.per_page
      end

      def max_csv_records
        10_000
      end

      def max_per_page
        10_000
      end

    end
  end
end
```

When the `paginate` config option is set to false, it defaults to the number value returned by `max_per_page`. If you're fine with overriding it globally, you can put this in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin_data_access.rb
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController < BaseController
    module DataAccess

      def max_per_page
        500 # was 10,000
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks ... let me check ... with your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this same question. I was unable to limit the number of records, so instead I have opted for putting a default value in one of my filters that guarantees an empty page when it loads.

(NOTE: I stole this idea from this stackoverflow question here:: [Set ActiveAdmin filter default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335297/set-activeadmin-filter-default-value) )

Example::
In this example, I set a filter called "my_filter_id" equal to "0" in the "before_filter" method if all of the parameters are blank.

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  before_filter my_filter_id: :index do
    params[:q] = {my_filter_id_eq: 0} if params[:commit].blank?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
`Post.limit(500)` instead of `Post.all.limit(500)` so it will minimize the latency.

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    Post.limit(500)
  end
end

index :pagination_total => false do
  selectable_column
  column :id
  column :user_name
  column :country
  column :city
end
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score -2):

Try below code. Replace something with your model name.

```
result = Something.find(:all, :order => "id desc", :limit => 5)

while !result.empty?
    puts result.pop
end
```

Comment: I dont need a general function. I need to override active_admin method.