# Set ActiveAdmin filter default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a simple filter in ActiveAdmin for boolean value. It looks like this

```
filter :invisible, as: :select
```

You may choose "any", "true" or "false" and it works just fine. But the default value of the filter is "any", while I need to set it to "true". How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an answer. You have to use `before_filter` so it is as simple as

```
controller do
  before_filter only: :index do
    params[:q] = {invisible_eq: true} if params[:commit].blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: How about something like this     

     redirect_to action: :index, q: { invisible_eq: true}, commit: "Filter"  params[:commit].blank?

This way the url refelcts your filter

Comment: You have a typo, it should be ```before_filter only: :index do```

Answer (score 1):

try some like this :

```
filter : invisible, as: :select, collection: [["Yes", true], ["No", false]]
```

This works fine for me.

Obviously you can edit the `"Yes"` - `"No"` string as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to copy the default search you want, eg active = true, and use that link. For example, rather than showing all users and changing default in code:

```
/people/users
```

Instead use this:

```
/people/users?qx%5Bactive%5D%5Bop%5D=null&qx%5Bactive%5D%5Bvalues%5D=true
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in admin page

```
ActiveAdmin.register YourModel do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Your Model Details" do
      f.input :yes_or_no, as: :select, collection: ['Yes', 'No'], include_blank: false, prompt: "Select Yes or No"
      
      # Add a class to the optional field to target it with JavaScript
      f.input :optional_field, input_html: { class: 'optional-field' }
    end

    f.actions
  end
end
```

try this in active admin.js

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  
  var yesOrNoSelect = document.querySelector('#your_model_yes_or_no');

  
  var optionalFieldInput = document.querySelector('.optional-field');

  
  yesOrNoSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
  
    if (yesOrNoSelect.value === 'Yes') {
      
      optionalFieldInput.required = true;
    } else {
      
      optionalFieldInput.required = false;
    }
  });
});
```